# SQL XML extract variable attribute names and values

Tags: sql, xml

I can't quite wrap my head around this one (even after a day reading stack overflow!)

I have a SQL table with an XML column. The root tag can have variable attribute names and quantity (up to 5) in it and I'd like to get the names and the data into a table with other information.

I've cobbled together a solution which will suffice but I really don't like it because I am using row_number to generate the field number and then joining it back, so I am relying on SQL extracting the attribute names in the correct order, and I am not sure this is reliable? It certainly doesn't feel it.

How should I go about doing this in a more robust way?

Example code with data

```
    ;with xmldata as (
SELECT 1 as id, 
CAST ('<CHG client="c;EN" work_order="c;130102">  <COL NAM="description" TYP="c">    <OLD>Electricity control on CONST01-CCU</OLD>    <NEW>Electricity control on CONST01-CCU93</NEW>
  </COL>  <COL NAM="last_update" TYP="d">    <OLD>2021-03-01 09:43:40</OLD>    <NEW>2021-03-01 09:43:40</NEW>  </COL></CHG>' AS XML) xml_data
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 as ID,  
  CAST( '<CHG menu_id="c;40906" user_id="c;" role_id="c;SYSTEM"><COL NAM="bflag" TYP="i"><NEW>8</NEW></COL><COL NAM="last_update" TYP="d"><NEW>2021-03-01 11:52:40</NEW>
  </COL><COL NAM="menu_id" TYP="c"><NEW>40906</NEW></COL><COL NAM="role_id" TYP="c"><NEW>SYSTEM</NEW></COL><COL NAM="tree_type" TYP="i">
  <NEW>1</NEW></COL><COL NAM="user_id" TYP="c"><NEW></NEW></COL><COL NAM="user_stamp" TYP="c"><NEW>TEST1</NEW></COL> </CHG> ' AS XML) as xml_data) 

  ,
cols as (SELECT id,  attrs.z.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as attr,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ) AS rowno
FROM xmldata d
CROSS APPLY d.xml_data.nodes('/CHG/@*') as attrs(z)
)


SELECT d.id,
cols1.attr key_1_name,
right( change.x.value('(@*)[1]','varchar(255)'), len(change.x.value('(@*)[1]','varchar(255)')) - charindex(';', change.x.value('(@*)[1]','varchar(255)'))) as key_1,
cols2.attr key_2_name,
right( change.x.value('(@*)[2]','varchar(255)'), len(change.x.value('(@*)[2]','varchar(255)')) - charindex(';', change.x.value('(@*)[2]','varchar(255)'))) as key_2,
cols3.attr key_3_name,
right( change.x.value('(@*)[3]','varchar(255)'), len(change.x.value('(@*)[3]','varchar(255)')) - charindex(';', change.x.value('(@*)[3]','varchar(255)'))) as key_3,
cols4.attr key_4_name,
right( change.x.value('(@*)[4]','varchar(255)'), len(change.x.value('(@*)[4]','varchar(255)')) - charindex(';', change.x.value('(@*)[4]','varchar(255)'))) as key_4,
cols5.attr key_5_name,
right( change.x.value('(@*)[5]','varchar(255)'), len(change.x.value('(@*)[5]','varchar(255)')) - charindex(';', change.x.value('(@*)[5]','varchar(255)'))) as key_5,

col.y.value('(@NAM)[1]','varchar(255)') as column_name,
col.y.value('(OLD)[1]','varchar(255)') as old_value,
col.y.value('(NEW)[1]','varchar(255)') as new_value
FROM xmldata d
OUTER APPLY d.xml_data.nodes('/CHG') as change(x)
OUTER APPLY d.xml_data.nodes('/CHG/COL') as col(y)
LEFT JOIN cols cols1 
ON d.id = cols1.id  AND cols1.rowno =1 
LEFT JOIN cols cols2
ON d.id = cols2.id  AND cols2.rowno =2
LEFT JOIN cols cols3
ON d.id = cols3.id  AND cols3.rowno =3
LEFT JOIN cols cols4
ON d.id = cols4.id  AND cols4.rowno =4
LEFT JOIN cols cols5
ON d.id = cols5.id  AND cols5.rowno =5
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Hmmm the dataset is all self contained being a CTE based query so I think 1 is moot, 2 and 3 I thought were given in my explanation, plus the desired result can be obtained from running the code, I am looking for a more robust way to implement the solution. The version is also pretty moot as I believe CTEs and XML data types have been around since 2005? So for completeness any version since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

Hierarchical XML supports implied relationships on its own pretty well via chained `CROSS APPLY` clause and a proper `.nodes()` method call.

So shredding is very easy.

**SQL #1**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xml_data XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xml_data) VALUES
(N'<CHG client="c;EN" work_order="c;130102">
    <COL NAM="description" TYP="c">
        <OLD>Electricity control on CONST01-CCU</OLD>
        <NEW>Electricity control on CONST01-CCU93</NEW>
    </COL>
    <COL NAM="last_update" TYP="d">
        <OLD>2021-03-01 09:43:40</OLD>
        <NEW>2021-03-01 09:43:40</NEW>
    </COL>
</CHG>'),
(N'<CHG menu_id="c;40906" user_id="c;" role_id="c;SYSTEM">
    <COL NAM="bflag" TYP="i">
        <NEW>8</NEW>
    </COL>
    <COL NAM="last_update" TYP="d">
        <NEW>2021-03-01 11:52:40</NEW>
    </COL>
    <COL NAM="menu_id" TYP="c">
        <NEW>40906</NEW>
    </COL>
    <COL NAM="role_id" TYP="c">
        <NEW>SYSTEM</NEW>
    </COL>
    <COL NAM="tree_type" TYP="i">
        <NEW>1</NEW>
    </COL>
    <COL NAM="user_id" TYP="c">
        <NEW></NEW>
    </COL>
    <COL NAM="user_stamp" TYP="c">
        <NEW>TEST1</NEW>
    </COL>
</CHG>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @prefix CHAR(2) = 'c;'
, @tilde CHAR(1) = '~'
, @separator CHAR(1) = ';';

SELECT id
    , a.value('local-name((@*)[1])', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS key1
    , REPLACE(a.value('(@*)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)'), @prefix, '') AS value1
    , a.value('local-name((@*)[2])', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS key2
    , REPLACE(a.value('(@*)[2]', 'VARCHAR(30)'), @prefix, '') AS value2
    , a.value('local-name((@*)[3])', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS key3
    , REPLACE(a.value('(@*)[3]', 'VARCHAR(30)'), @prefix, '') AS value3
    , a.value('local-name((@*)[4])', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS key4
    , REPLACE(a.value('(@*)[4]', 'VARCHAR(30)'), @prefix, '') AS value4
    , a.value('local-name((@*)[5])', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS key5
    , REPLACE(a.value('(@*)[5]', 'VARCHAR(30)'), @prefix, '') AS value5
    , y.value('@NAM', 'varchar(255)') AS column_name
    , y.value('(OLD/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS old_value
    , y.value('(NEW/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS new_value
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY xml_data.nodes('/CHG') AS t1(a)
    CROSS APPLY t1.a.nodes('COL') AS t2(y);
```

**SQL #2**

A more generic approach to get rid of the **c;** prefix. It requires SQL Server 2016 and later. That's the reason for the #4 of a minimal reproducible example.

```
SELECT id
    , a.value('local-name((@*)[1])', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS key1
    , REPLACE(a.value('(@*)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)'), @prefix, '') AS value1
    , (
      SELECT LEFT(s.value, LEN(s.value) - 1)
      FROM STRING_SPLIT(a.value('(@*)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') + @tilde, @separator) AS s
      WHERE s.value LIKE '%' + @tilde
      ) AS value1
    , a.value('local-name((@*)[2])', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS key2
    , REPLACE(a.value('(@*)[2]', 'VARCHAR(30)'), @prefix, '') AS value2
    , a.value('local-name((@*)[3])', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS key3
    , REPLACE(a.value('(@*)[3]', 'VARCHAR(30)'), @prefix, '') AS value3
    , a.value('local-name((@*)[4])', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS key4
    , REPLACE(a.value('(@*)[4]', 'VARCHAR(30)'), @prefix, '') AS value4
    , a.value('local-name((@*)[5])', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS key5
    , REPLACE(a.value('(@*)[5]', 'VARCHAR(30)'), @prefix, '') AS value5
    , y.value('@NAM', 'varchar(255)') AS column_name
    , y.value('(OLD/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS old_value
    , y.value('(NEW/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS new_value
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY xml_data.nodes('/CHG') AS t1(a)
    CROSS APPLY t1.a.nodes('COL') AS t2(y);
```

Comment: Thank you, the syntax I needed was: change.x.value('local-name((@*)[1])', 'VARCHAR(30)')

Comment: @AdamDavies, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please up-vote: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali